# Как передать переменную в функцию и получить результат вычислений?

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, я хочу сделать так, чтобы главная функция передавала данные вспомогательной, а вспомогательная в свою очередь возвращала результат вычислений главной.
Я написал код, и в нем две функции главная show и вспомогательная female:

```js
function show(a){
    o4in= document.getElementById("name").value;
    o4o=female().call;
    document.getElementById("boolean").innerHTML=o4o;
}

function female(x) {
    o4in= document.getElementById("name").value;
    mnim= o4in.split('');
    mntt=[0,0];
    mntt[0]=(rlarim1.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?1:(rlarim2.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?2:(rlarim3.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?3:(rlarim4.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?4:(rlarim5.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?5:(rlarim6.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?6:(rlarim7.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?7:(rlarim8.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?8:(rlarim9.search(mnim[0]) != -1)?9:0;
    mntta1=(rlarim1.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?1:(rlarim2.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?2:(rlarim3.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?3:(rlarim4.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?4:(rlarim5.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?5:(rlarim6.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?6:(rlarim7.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?7:(rlarim8.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?8:(rlarim9.search(mnim[1]) != -1)?9:0;mntt[1]=(1 in mnim)? mntta1:0;
    ........
    mntta29=(rlarim1.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?1:(rlarim2.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?2:(rlarim3.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?3:(rlarim4.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?4:(rlarim5.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?5:(rlarim6.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?6:(rlarim7.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?7:(rlarim8.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?8:(rlarim9.search(mnim[29]) != -1)?9:0;mntt[29]=(29 in mnim)? mntta29:0;
    o4a=mntt.reduce((sum, current) => sum + current, 0);
    o4b=Math.trunc(o4a/100)+Math.trunc((o4a%100)/10)+(o4a%10);
    o4=(o4a>22)?o4b:o4a;
    return o4;
}
```

Comment: Возможно, не помешает дать читателям больше контекста. Что делают ваши функции, какие данные они принимают и отдают. Ваш код сам по себе не очень читабелен, имена переменных загадочны, слишком неотформатированная запись без пробелов, поэтому с ходу трудно понять, в чём суть.

Comment: Сейчас все поясню первая функция она же главная берет данные из формы (в данном случае имя) и отображает в контейнере результат вычислений, которые в свою очередь делает вторая она же вспомогательная (она переводит буквы в цифры, а затем суммирует). Но это теория, а на практике обмена данными между функциями не происходит.

Comment: А `female().call` это что? Откуда там свойство `.call` ? И почему не задаётся аргумент `x` если он описан в `female` ?

Comment: " чтобы главная функция передавала данные вспомогательной" - какие именно данные? `a` или `o4in` или что-то ещё?

Comment: Pavel Grisharev спасибо за ответ все заработало. И прям так как надо(без привязки к конкретной функции.